# Bing Maps in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bing-maps

How to integrate Bing Maps into iPhone Application?
I am doing using VirtualEarthKit framework [website appears to host malware].
My code is as below :
I am getting error while getting token.

```
{
 VECommonService *commonService = [[VECommonService alloc] init];
 NSString *token;
 printf("2\n");
 NSError *error=[commonService getToken:&token forUserID:@"abc" password:@"def" ipAddress:@"123"];

 NSString *errMsg= [error description];
 printf("\n%s\n",[errMsg UTF8String]);

  printf("3\n");

 VEGeocodeService *geocodeService = [[VEGeocodeService alloc] init];

 VEGeocodeRequest *geocodeRequest = [[VEGeocodeRequest alloc] init];
  printf("4\n");
 geocodeRequest.query = @"Portland State University";
 geocodeRequest.token = token;

printf("5\n");

 VEServiceResponse *geocodeResponse = [geocodeService geocode:geocodeRequest];

 VEGeocodeResult *geocodeResult = [geocodeResponse.results objectAtIndex:0];


 //NSLog([geocodeResult.location description]);
 //NSLog([geocodeResult.address description]);

 VEImageryService *imageryService = [[VEImageryService alloc] init];

 VEGetMapURIRequest *mapRequest = [[VEGetMapURIRequest alloc] init];

 mapRequest.center = geocodeResult.location;
 mapRequest.token = token;


 VEGetMapURIResponse *mapResponse = [imageryService getMapURI:mapRequest];





 NSURL *url = mapResponse.mapURL;

 //printf("\n\n URL==> %s",[url relativeString]);
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
 [self.view addSubview:webView]; 
}
```

is there any way to use bing maps in an iPhone app?

Comment: -1 link to unsafe area..

Comment: Yep, no chance of helping without a malware-free link to the framework. Bing Maps' Ajax framework inside a UIWebView is an option.